how to sort context menu in Project Explorer
I'm currently trying to make a plugin I've created show a menu in the Project Explorer.
This plugin consists of several projects:

com.business.a project
com.business.b project

The plugin.xml of the com.business.a project is as follows:

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
   <category id="com.business.product.ui.newWizards.category" name="%category.name"/>
   <wizard
      category="com.business.product.ui.newWizards.category"
      class="com.business.a.wizard.NewFileWizard"
      hasPages="true"
      icon="icon/model/a.gif"
      id="com.business.a.new.wizards.core.newFileWizard"
      name="%wizard.name"
      project="">
       <description>%wizard.description</description>
    </wizard>
 </extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
   <commonWizard
      menuGroupId="productGroup"
      type="new"
      wizardId="com.business.a.new.wizards.core.newFileWizard>
      <enablement>
         <and>
            <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
               <equals value="com.business.a.perspective.design"/>
            </with>
         </and>
      </enablement>
   </commonWizard>
</extension>


The plugin.xml of the com.business.b project is as follows:
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
   <wizard
      category="com.business.product.ui.newWizard.category"
      class="com.business.b.wizard.ImportWizard"
      icon="icons/b.gif"
      id="com.business.b.new.wizards.extension.ImportWizard"
      name="%wizard.name">
   </wizard>
 </extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
   <commonWizard
      menuGroupId="productGroup"
      type="new"
      wizardId="com.business.b.new.wizards.extension.ImportWizard">
    <enablement>
   <and>
 <with variable="activeWorkbenchWindow.activePerspective">
 <equals value="com.business.b.perspective.design" />
 </with>
 </and>
 </enablement>
 </commonWizard>
</extension>

I tried several methods.
First, it was determined by the spelling order of the id of the org.eclipse.ui.newWizards extension point,
so I did com.business.a.newWizards, com.business.b.newWizards
but it didn't work.
Even with the priority property, it didn't work..
In conclusion, I just had to change the wizard's name.

new File
Import File

But I don't want to change the name.
Is there any way?

Surely Import should be in the Import menu, not the New menu

From what I can make out the wizards are always sorted alphabetically - code is in  org.eclipse.ui.navigator.WizardActionGroup

@greg-449 import is just an example name.. The example was confusing.
As you said, it is in alphabetical order, but I want to adjust it arbitrarily.

Like I said you can't do this, the code doesn't support it.
